# What is the meaning of $X \in \mathcal {F}$ in probability space ${\displaystyle (\Omega ,{\mathcal {F}},P)}$?

Tags: probability, martingale

I'm studying Martingales.

In the text I keep finding  $X \in \mathcal {F}$ with random variable $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. And $\mathcal {F}$ a $\sigma$-algebra of $\Omega$. What does it mean?

Comment: In English we often say "$X$ is an *event.*"  All this means is that it's a set to which a probability can be associated.  As far as what "random variable" means, please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=random%20variable%20sigma%20algebra).

Comment: @whuber I think here $X$ is a random variable, not an event. $X \in \mathcal{F}$ is a conventional shorthand for $X \in \mathcal{F}/\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Literally, $X\in \mathcal F$ means $F$ is a member of the set $\mathcal F,$ which contains no random variables at all.  Your second statement "$X \in \mathcal{F}/\mathbb{R}$" makes little sense because $\mathbb{R}$ is not a subset of $\mathcal F.$

Comment: @whuber While I totally see your point, I have some vague impression that some author used this "$X \in \mathcal{F}$" notation to denote the more rigorous meaning "$X$ is a $\mathcal{F}$-measurable function (i.e., random variable)". Possibly from the text *Probability with Martingales* by *David Williams*. Maybe the OP should add the source from which he saw this notation. On the other hand, I agree with you that the "$\in \mathcal{F}$" notation should be better reserved for events instead of r.v.s.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Williams is careful with his notation, but nevertheless I just looked at every page in his first three chapters (the introductory material) and cannot find any such abuse.  To be sure, writers do abuse notation (although rarely that badly); but they usually announce it when they do.

Comment: @whuber Great! I looked it up too (turns out my impression is not precise) . He actually used "$X \in m\mathcal{F}$", which makes much more sense. In conclusion, I vote for not using $X \in \mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's shorthand for saying $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable (i.e., that $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in B\} \in \mathcal{F}$ for every Borel set $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$).

Comment: "$\{X \in B\} \in \mathcal{F}$" is not mathematically well-formed (it makes no sense): most likely there's a typographical error in there, but what did you intend it to mean?

Comment: @whuber Sorry, it's more shorthand. It stands for the preimage of $B$ under $X$: $\{X \in B\} = X^{-1}(B) = \{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in B\}$. I'm so used to seeing it that I didn't even think about clarifying it. I'll make an edit to the answer.

Comment: I think ,the condition $B\subset \mathbb R$ is not true.

Comment: @Masoud yes, which is why I quantify it as “Borel set $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Artem Mavrin, I did not see it!

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is  $\mathcal {F}$-measurable , if $\sigma(X)\subset \mathcal {F}$ , where

$$\sigma(X)=X^{-1}(Borel(\mathbb R))=\{X^{-1}(B): B\in Borel(\mathbb R) \}$$,that is,

$$\forall B\in Borel(\mathbb R) \hspace{.6cm} X^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal {F}$$

where $X^{-1}(B)=\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega)\in B\}$.

Comment: As discussed in comments to the question, "$X\in\mathfrak{F}$" can at best be considered an abuse of notation, because it makes no mathematical sense.  Thus your "we say" is unlikely to be correct.  I would stand corrected if you could find any authoritative reference that adopts or advocates this notation.

Comment: @whuber , You right and I agree with you. It is edited.

Comment: @whuber while I agree that writing "$X \in \mathcal{F}$" is an abuse of notation (I personally don't like it), it is nevertheless an established notation in the probability literature. For example, see [Resnick's *A Probability Path*, bottom of page 74](https://books.google.com/books?id=T9-PMDSVDNsC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: If $X:(\Omega,\mathcal B)\rightarrow (\Omega^{\prime},\mathcal B^{\prime}) $,
$X$ is measurable if $X^{-1}(\mathcal B^{\prime})\subset \mathcal B$. 
The notation $X\in \mathcal B/\mathcal B^{\prime}$ is look good since it depend on $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal B^{\prime}$. But in the notation $X\in \mathcal F$, we just see one side.

Comment: @Masoud yes, the idea is that $X \in \mathcal{F}$ is short for $X \in \mathcal{F}/\mathrm{Borel}(\mathbb{R})$. Usually context will make it clear whether $X$ is an event or a random variable. Again, I'm not trying to defend the notation, just pointing out that it is common.